# требуется помощь со cтроками

Tags: python, python-3.x

Преобразовать последовательность s1, ..., sn , заменив запятыми все двоеточия, встречающиеся среди s1, ..., s[n / 2] , и заменив точками все восклицательные знаки, встречающиеся среди s[n / 2]+1, ..., sn

```
g=input()
n=len(g)
for i in range (int(n/2)):
    g=g.replace(":",",")
    j=g
u=int((n/2)+1)
for u in range(n):
    f=j.replace('!','.')
print(f)
```

нужно заменить только в перовой половине строки все : на , а во второй ! на . f я пытался реализовать через цикл но программа игнорирует цикл и делает во всей строке замену

Comment: 1) Разумеется, игнорирует, посмотрите синтаксис replace. Всегда начинайте с чтения синтаксиса метода используемого. 2) Я бы строку преобразовал в список, а затем в цикле менял. Или считайте maxcount и оставьте replace.

Comment: Сделайте срезы нужных частей строки, в них замените что нужно, потом обратно склейте. Циклы нужны только если будете посимвольно менять, не через replace